# SSRS cascading @parameters are not working

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssms, ssrs-2012

I have 2 Parameters:
Region (Parent)
Program (Child)

My goal is to set them the way that if I'd pick the certain Region -> then only Programs associated with that Region will be populated.

Region table fields:
ID
RegionName

My query for the Region (Parent) parameter (@RegionID):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                 [ID] 
                ,[Region]
FROM             [Region]

WHERE            ([ID] <> -1) -- to exclude N/R Regions

ORDER BY         [Region]
```

Program table fields:
ID
ProgramName

My query for Program (Child) parameter (@ProgramID):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                [ID] 
               ,[ProgramName]

FROM            [Program]

WHERE           ([ID] <> -1) -- to exclude N/R Programs
            AND ([ID] IN (@RegionID))  

ORDER BY        [ProgramName]
```

I also have ((RegionID IN (@RegionID)) AND (ProgramID IN (@ProgramID))) in my main code.

But query N2 (Program parameter) returns empty table (no records).
I know I have to select specifically RegionID in query N2.
While it is now refers to ID which belongs to Program, not to Region.

How can I say I need Region ID there?
(Both tables have the same ID names and they are not connected between each other)

Please advice!
Thank you.

Comment: How can [ID] ever have two different values?

Answer (score 0):

You could alias your columns like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                 RegionID = [ID] 
                ,[Region]
FROM             [Region]

WHERE            ([ID] <> -1) -- to exclude N/R Regions

ORDER BY         [Region]
```